# Passing function to R regex-based tools

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

This string manipulation problem has evaded my best efforts. I have a string, e.g.

```
eg_str="[probability space](posts/probability space.md) is ... [Sigma Field](posts/Sigma Field.md)"
```

for which I would like to replace all spaces in the wildcard for ([wildcard].md) with underscores. My first thought was to use either gsub or stringr's str_replace_all to pass the appropriate substrings to a simple function. Something like

```
convert_space_to_underscore<-function(string){
    return(str_replace(string," ","_"))
}
normal_eg_str<-gsub("\\((.+?)md\\)",paste0("(",convert_space_to_underscore("\\1"),"md)"),normal_eg_str)
```

or

```
normal_eg_str<-str_replace_all(document,"\\((.+?)md\\)",paste0("(",convert_space_to_underscore("\\1"),".md)"))
```

When I run these however, it appears that the argument to `convert_space_to_underscore` is being passed, rather than the output, because the string returns unchanged (if you make an error in the paste0 component, say have `paste0("(",convert_space_to_underscore("\\1"),".m)")`, then the string returns as

```
eg_str="[probability space](posts/probability space.m) is ... [Sigma Field](posts/Sigma Field.m)"
```

so I'm quite sure that what is happening is that str_replace_all and gsub are simply not evaluating the function).

Is there a way to force evaluation? This would be most ideal, as it would allow for the regex component to remain somewhat readable. However, I would welcome any pure-regex solutions as well — my attempts have all lead to greedy errors, no matter where I seem to sprinkle `?` and `{0}` special characters. (Word of caution: there will be some matching substrings with more than one space e.g. `[Dynklin's Pi Lambda](posts/dynklins pi lambda.md)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
eg_str <- "[probability space](posts/probability space.md) is ... [Sigma Field](posts/Sigma Field.md)"
str_replace_all(eg_str, "\\([^()]+\\.md\\)", function(x) gsub(" ", "_", x, fixed=TRUE) )
## => [1] "[probability space](posts/probability_space.md) is ... [Sigma Field](posts/Sigma_Field.md)"
```

See [online R demo](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCsIwFET3PcUnqwRrvIAu9QBWV00NSRvDh7QNSQrt6WNEBMHNMMybYULODnVQYaMxBZxsYJWxsng47oG0PsxaaXSYNohe9aajfo4pHv4AHwcGGIFzDm2DdlRwQeOG7@AneldJVT5kMN6VrVTO0c9tDUQI2j4o63ZClKYQjNTwXKY@4TzRlYGNi6YESkpkkbVQXM1wul3vZwYs5xc).

**NOTE**: To replace one or more whitespace chunks with a single underscore, you will need a regex in `gsub`: `gsub("\\s+", "_", x)`.

The [first regex](https://regex101.com/r/k4cwMZ/1) finds all strings that

- `\(` - start with `(`
- `[^()]+` - have one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\.md` - a `.md` string
- `\)` - and end with `)`

Then, the match is passed to an anonymous function that replaced each regular space with a `_` (with `gsub(" ", "_", x, fixed=TRUE)`).

A base R solution (less readable, but using a plain regex):

```r
eg_str <- "[probability space](posts/probability space.md) is ... [Sigma Field](posts/Sigma Field.md)"
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\()[^()\\s]*\\K\\s+(?=[^()]*\\.md\\))", "_", eg_str, perl=TRUE)
```

See [this R demo online](https://ideone.com/G8Tclf). See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7wFbJ8/1). Details:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\()` - end of the preceding match or a `(` char
- `[^()\s]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `(`, `)` and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[^()]*\.md\))` - there should be zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` followed with `.md)` immediately to the right of the current location.